# Why doesn't chaining fuser command and node app work in sequence?

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, command-line, command-line-arguments

The following command work as anticipated independently:

```
fuser -k 12345/tcp 

nodemon app
```

However

```
fuser -k 35243/tcp && nodemon app
```

just returns the result of the first command / returns to the command line.

Why can't these command be chained?

(Also attempted a sleep in between the commands)

Comment: Does the `fuser` command return an error code? In order to continue to the next one with `&&` it needs to report a success.

Comment: Would no result (i.e., no process to kill) be considered an error?

Comment: Depends on the actual exit code of the command. See for example: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-get-exit-code-of-command/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/fuser.1.html

> fuser returns a non-zero return code if none of the specified
> files is accessed or in case of a fatal error.  If at least one
> access has been found, fuser returns zero.

The `&&` operator short-circuits and only executes the second command if the first one returned zero ("success").  So if the socket was not already in use, then `fuser` returns nonzero and `nodemon app` is not executed.

If you want to execute the second command regardless of the result of the first one, use `;` instead of `&&`:

```
fuser -k 35243/tcp ; nodemon app
```

This would be exactly the same as listing them on two lines.